# List<String> to Map<String. String> in Dart to firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to dart, Interestingly I was trying to convert the List of values to Map. Under List simple string of list that's it.

So far none of this worked,

```
  var map2 = value.asMap();
              print(map2);
              var map1 = Map.fromIterable(value,
                  key: (e) => e.toString(), value: (e) => e);
              print(map1);
              var map = Map<String, String>.fromIterable(value);
              print(map);
```

Firestore complains that only can save Map<String, String>. So the above method all fails.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but could you post what code you're using to save this map to Firestore, as well as the message provided by error log? I'd like to understand the issue a little bit better, as, to my knowledge, firestore accepts pretty much any map. Heck, I'm pretty sure that you could turn your iterable list into an array and store the whole array into a single map entry (though each entry in the array will still count as a map entry, and the indexation does have a cap in Firestore, iirc).

Comment: Hey, Fabc. I was trying to convert list to map, it was wrong, Don't bother closing it now.Thanks!